# matplotlib graph fill 2 colors above and below axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a line graph which is partly above and below the x-axis of `0`.
How can I color all the area above the line green, and all below red?
Here's the code:

```
hydropathy_dict = {"I":-0.528, 
        "L":-0.342,
        "F":-0.370,
        "V":-0.308,
        "M":-0.324,
        "P":-0.322,
        "W": -0.270,
        "H": 2.029,
        "T": 0.853,
        "E": 3.173,
        "Q": 2.176,
        "C": 0.081,
        "Y": 1.677,
        "A":-0.495,
        "S": 0.936,
        "N": 2.354,
        "D": 9.573,
        "R": 4.383,
        "G": 0.386,
        "K": 2.101
        }
    seq = 'CHCRRSCYSTEYSYGTCTVMGINHRFCC'
    hydropathy_list = []
    plot_x_axis = []
    for aa in seq:
        hydropathy_list.append(hydropathy_dict[aa])
    print(acc,hydropathy_list)
    for i in range(len(hydropathy_list)):
        plot_x_axis.append(i)

    plt.plot(plot_x_axis,hydropathy_list)
    plt.plot([0,len(hydropathy_list)],[0,0])
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

hydropathy_dict = {"I":-0.528, 
        "L":-0.342,
        "F":-0.370,
        "V":-0.308,
        "M":-0.324,
        "P":-0.322,
        "W": -0.270,
        "H": 2.029,
        "T": 0.853,
        "E": 3.173,
        "Q": 2.176,
        "C": 0.081,
        "Y": 1.677,
        "A":-0.495,
        "S": 0.936,
        "N": 2.354,
        "D": 9.573,
        "R": 4.383,
        "G": 0.386,
        "K": 2.101
        }

seq = 'CHCRRSCYSTEYSYGTCTVMGINHRFCC'
hydropathy_list = []
plot_x_axis = []
for aa in seq:
    hydropathy_list.append(hydropathy_dict[aa])

#print(seq, hydropathy_list)
for i in range(len(hydropathy_list)):
    plot_x_axis.append(i)

# convert to np array
hydropathy_list = np.array(hydropathy_list)
plot_x_axis = np.array(plot_x_axis)

# densify data for filled color plot
f = interpolate.interp1d(plot_x_axis, hydropathy_list)
xnew = np.arange(plot_x_axis[0], plot_x_axis[-1], 0.1)
ynew = f(xnew)

plt.plot(plot_x_axis, hydropathy_list)       # blue line
plt.plot([0, len(hydropathy_list)], [0,0])   # green line

# use xnew, ynew to plot filled-color graphs
plt.fill_between(xnew, 0, ynew, where=(ynew-1) < -1 , color='red')
plt.fill_between(xnew, 0, ynew, where=(ynew-1) > -1 , color='green')

plt.show()
```

[image: with interpolated points]

**Edit**

(In response of the questions in the comment)

Statement `where=(ynew-1)<-1` inside `fill_between()` requires `ynew` as a numpy array (simple list won't work).

Scipy.interpolate() is used to get more points along the curve, so that, the color fills the target areas completely.

With the original points, the result looks like this:

[image: with original points]

Comment: Thank you, even with the other comments I couldn't get it to work completely. Are interpolate and numpy's array needed or are there matplotlib solutions too?

Comment: @RnRoger, I have edited my answer to clarify some of your questions. To get denser points for the curve, you can also use `np.arange()` for each segment of the data and `np.concaternate()` them. If you still have problem, you can always post it as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [matplotlib fill-between demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/fill_between_demo.html). That will surely answer your question.

But that being said your code doesn't show any figure definition which makes this more difficult. Usually you do the following:

```
fig, ax = plt.figure()
ax.plot(plot_x_axis, line_1)
ax.plot(plot_x_axis, line_2)
ax.fill_between(plot_x_axis, line_1, line_2, color='r')
ax.fill_between(plot_x_axis, line_2, line_1, color='g')
```

Comment: Why should I use a figure? Is that better in this case?

Comment: It makes working with the plot much easier and if you want multiple plots it disambiguates between them. Also if you need multiple axes with a figure this is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

use this format:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(10)
plt.fill_between(x,0,100,color='red')
plt.fill_between(x,0,-100,color='blue')

plt.show()
```